# Need help for javascript and trigonometry

Tags: javascript, game-physics

http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/CxFRC/15/ all chrome only **click and drag, up and back arrow.**

pastebin.com/gXS1J7zw

**The Problem:** I can't make `c=$('.con')` go/translate sideways. I have managed to do front and backward. But I cant workout the formula for sideways.

This is my first attempt. Use arrows keys, forward and backward works are in different function. But leftRight don't.

**Code in question:** you don't need to worry about rest of the code main logic for right left lies here. I have tried finding the perpendicular angle but it behaves opposite and then opposite of opposite.

First code that works and need no attention:

```
function forwBack(x){ 
   az+= x*(Math.cos((Math.PI/180)*ry))*Math.cos((Math.PI/180)*rx)*speed;
   ax-= x*(Math.sin((Math.PI/180)*ry))*Math.cos((Math.PI/180)*rx)*speed;
   ay+= x*(Math.sin((Math.PI/180)*rx))*speed; 
}
```

Now code that doesn't do what I want... translate perpendicular to vector.

```
     function rightLeft(x){
       az+= Math.sin(ry*(Math.PI/180))*(Math.cos((rx+90)*(Math.PI/180))*speed*x);
       ax-= Math.cos(ry*(Math.PI/180))*(Math.cos((rx+90)*(Math.PI/180))*speed*x);
       ay+= Math.sin((rx+90)*(Math.PI/180))*speed*x; 
    }
```

x is sign which determines left/right or forward/backward. Speed is hypotenuse here. Pi/180 for deg to radians. And  180/Pi for radians to deg. (rotation around x axis) rx and ry are defined in function ch..and represent rotation of main(.ma) container. rx is defined by vertical movement of mouse.

I don't need to do this, but I want to. I want to make 3d explorer like a hall.. Just for fun. I used to do this kind of stuff in flash like 9 years ago. I was a kid then.

MAIN problem is that sideways is not always -x or +x, it depends on how much outer container has been rotated(around xyz). So if m is rotated 90 around y axis only telling c to move x+ would make c actually look like it's going back or reducing in z.

After trying two days straight I can't fix this.

http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/hGkMj/1/ -- Checking out 3d

http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/hGkMj/6/ -- Checking out 3d

http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/9YjSC/3  I made this to get clear idea of what I was trying to do. Move mouse, & Use arrow keys. Need to click in the preview window.

Comment: Is there supposed to be a 3D effect? I don't see it at all when playing on your jsfiddle link with the arrow keys

Comment: you have chrome right?

Comment: OK, I was with Firefox, with Chrome I can see the 3D.

Comment: It looks that in the function rightLeft, the abscissa and ordinates are inverted. I don't understand how you are getting rx and ry but maybe you should try swapping them.

Comment: rx and ry are defined in function ch..and are meant to represent rotation of main(.ma) container. rx, rotation around x axis, is defined by vertical movement of mouse. and i have tried many things including that.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/CxFRC/18/ more fun

Comment: Why there is no answer here

Comment: I was trying to understand the code better, but last time I wanted to run it on the browser, and somehow I couldn't make a web page the puts together the .css and .js you wrote and put on jsfiddle. Could you put that somewhere if it's not too much to ask?

Comment: here you go: http://pastebin.com/gXS1J7zw :D

Comment: 80% sure there is something wrong with my understanding of geometry. And what is perpendicular in 3d.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. In your function rightLeft, you are inverting x and y.
I rewrote the function and it is working fine:

```
    function rightLeft(x){
        var dAy = 0 ; 
        var dAz = Math.cos((ry+90)*(Math.PI/180))*speed*x;
        var dAx = Math.sin((rx+90)*(Math.PI/180))*speed*x;
        console.log("dAx = " + dAx + " dAz = " + dAz + " dAy = " + dAy);
        ax-= dAx;
        az+= dAz;
        ay+= dAy;
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: ugh still doesn't work. It goes right and left when looking straight but once you move mouse. The direction remains the same right left doesn't get changed with rx and ry to new right or left